# Cygwin: Deleting file when handle is opened

Tags: c++, windows, file, winapi, cygwin

I have a file which I want to delete, it's handle is held by system process so everytime I try to delete it it gives `Access denied` but for some reason cygwin is able to delete it.

I've downloaded the coreutils and investigated the source code of `rm` executable and found that it uses `unlink` function to achieve it. I've created a little test program which uses same function but it gives me `Access denied` anyway.

Then I found this [article](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2011-10/msg00386.html) and guy describes how cygwin is able to delete a file which is the following:

> Cygwin opens files always with all sharing flags
>   set, so a file opened by a Cygwin process should not result in a sharing
>   violation in another open call.  The exception is the first NtOpenFile
>   in unlink_nt, which opens the file with FILE_SHARE_DELETE only to find
>   out if the file has an open handle somewhere else.  In that case it gets
>   a STATUS_SHARING_VIOLATION, the next NtOpenFile will open the file with
>   all sharing flags set, and unlink_nt will try to delete the file or to
>   rename it, or to move it to the recycle bin, dependent on its path.

Which makes sense, So I started to implement same thing. Here is my code:

```
HANDLE file;
PIO_STATUS_BLOCK stat;

UNICODE_STRING myUnicodeStr;
RtlInitUnicodeString(&myUnicodeStr, L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TSU\\bin\\TSU.sys");

POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES attr;
InitializeObjectAttributes (attr, &myUnicodeStr, OBJ_OPENIF, NULL, NULL);

NtOpenFile(&file, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, attr, NULL, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, FILE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE);

NtClose(file);
```

As you can see I'm trying to open file with sharing flags set and also used `FILE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` since I close the handle and I want it to be deleted afterwards.

The problem I have is `Segmentation Fault`(I'm using cygwin win10) for some reason. Little debugging showed that problem is in `InitializeObjectAttributes` function for some reason.

**P.S**
I know it's not the best solution to delete file when it's handle is held by some other process but the main goal is to mimic the `rm.exe`'s behaviour in this way. Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: `POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES attr;` - and for what point `attr` how you think ?

Comment: and anyway impossible delete file while it have another handles open or section on it

Comment: Thanks for response I point it to `NULL` but have seg fault again. but how does cygwin achieve it? after rm file is not in same directory anymore. I haven't seen coping file to another directory in `rm.exe` source code.

Comment: *I point it to NULL but have seg fault again* - at first on windows not exist seg fault at all. at second - what sense point it no 0 ? and if file in use impossible delete it.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/WeUvZMM6 Here is the strace of the rm.exe, then what does `rm.exe` do?

Comment: Change `POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES attr; InitializeObjectAttributes (attr, ...);` to `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES attr; InitializeObjectAttributes (&attr, ...);`, and then pass `&attr` to `NtOpenFile()`

Comment: "*opens the file with FILE_SHARE_DELETE only to find out if the file has an open handle somewhere else*" - opening the file with exclusive access (no sharing rights) would do the same thing.

Comment: again - do simply test - run some exe, and try delete it while it running

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for reply, I've changed the way you suggested and now it doesn't bring any error, but the file handle still exist in system process and file is not deleted.

Comment: because file can not be deleted while it in use.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but what does cygwin's `rm.exe` do? even if file is in use I can still use rm and file is dissapeared from the folder. I pasted the strace log and it really seems to do something with the file. check this log:

Comment: 22274 1312623 [main] rm 5836 try_to_bin: Overwriting with another file failed, status = 0xC0000022
  112 1312735 [main] rm 5836 try_to_bin: \??\C:\Program Files (x86)\TSU\bin\TSU.sys, return bin_status 2
   47 1312782 [main] rm 5836 unlink_nt: \??\C:\Program Files (x86)\TSU\bin\TSU.sys, return status = 0x0
   69 1312851 [main] rm 5836 unlink: 0 = unlink(C:\Program Files (x86)\TSU\bin\TSU.sys)
 1046 1313897 [main] rm 5836 close: close(0)

Comment: @Jakomo - are you listen me - do simply test - run exe file and try delete it with your *rm.exe* while it running.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you saying that. Yes I tried and it was able to delete it.

Comment: this impossible in windows

Comment: 1) https://imgur.com/a/8jukQ
2) https://imgur.com/a/YDO5n
3) https://imgur.com/a/39zn8
4) https://imgur.com/a/XRt2j

Comment: @Jakomo - are you run this under windows ? images nothing say for me. paths format not from windows. if you paste *rm.exe* instead images and logs - i can say what it really doing

Comment: yes its windows, paths are different because its under cygwin. You mean source code of `rm.exe`?

Comment: no, of course binary file.

Comment: *paths are different because its under cygwin* - no, run it **under windows** and check result

Comment: i mean next - run some exe **under windows** and try delete it while this exe - **under windows** but not in some shell, running

Comment: so you can try delete running exe from cygwin or from windows, but exe must direct run under windows

Comment: https://ufile.io/fnltu  here is the picture of deleting it while process was running. https://imgur.com/a/273oG

Comment: i need also *cygwin1.dll*  and *cygintl-8.dll* for run *rm.exe*

Comment: while i download some version of *cygwin1.dll* it not export *rpmatch* function (it imported by *rm.exe*) if you upload your version of cygwin1.dll cygintl-8.dll and cygiconv-2.dll - can look what rm.exe really do

Comment: it really not delete file of course but move it to `$Recycle.Bin`

Comment: https://ufile.io/1lauu https://ufile.io/q3rtn sorry for late response I had some network issue, how did you find that out?

Comment: look in $Recycle.Bin (om same disk) for "deleted" file

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand something, I did what you asked, run app directly from windows (double click as I understand) and delete it with cmd and this is image of `$Recycle.Bin` https://imgur.com/a/tGGeB plus I `dir` the directory and this is what I get https://imgur.com/a/Uj28o

Comment: *rm.exe* can not delete exe file until exe is running. it simply **move** it to *$Recycle.Bin*

Comment: I understand. But why I can't see the actual file in `$Recycle.Bin`?

Comment: may be you bad looking. i advice set you bp under debugger to `ZwSetInformationFile`. first time it called with `FileDispositionInformation` and this call failed with `STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE` and than called with `FileRenameInformation`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

under windows not always possible delete file. for example when some process mapping this file as an image

if try delete **running** *EXE* file with *rm.exe* - it first call [`ZwOpenFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567011(v=vs.85).aspx) with `DesiredAccess = DELETE`, `ShareAccess = FILE_SHARE_DELETE` and `OpenOptions = FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT`. this is ok. than called [`ZwSetInformationFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567096(v=vs.85).aspx) with `FileDispositionInformation` - the `DeleteFile` from [`FILE_DISPOSITION_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545765(v=vs.85).aspx) set to *TRUE*. this call failed with status `STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE`.

filesystem return `STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE` exactly from [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/fastfat/fileinfo.c#L2477) place:

```
        //  Make sure there is no process mapping this file as an image.

        if (!MmFlushImageSection( &Fcb->NonPaged->SectionObjectPointers,
                                  MmFlushForDelete )) {

            DebugTrace(-1, Dbg, "Cannot delete user mapped image\n", 0);

            return STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE;
}
```

than *rm.exe* again try open file, already with `OpenOptions = FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT | FILE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` options. but this call of course fail with the same `STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE`. now error from [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/fastfat/create.c#L3577) point:

```
//  If the user wants to delete on close, we must check at this
//  point though.
//

if (FlagOn(*DesiredAccess, FILE_WRITE_DATA) || DeleteOnClose) {

    Fcb->OpenCount += 1;
    DecrementFcbOpenCount = TRUE;

    if (!MmFlushImageSection( &Fcb->NonPaged->SectionObjectPointers,
                              MmFlushForWrite )) {

        Iosb.Status = DeleteOnClose ? STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE :
                                      STATUS_SHARING_VIOLATION;
        try_return( Iosb );
    }
}
```

after this *rm.exe* again call [`ZwSetInformationFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567096(v=vs.85).aspx) already with `FileRenameInformation` - where `RootDirectory` from [`FILE_RENAME_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540344(v=vs.85).aspx) point to volume (on which file located) root (so like `\Device\HarddiskVolume<N>\` and `FileName` point to some path in recycle bin. as result file actually moved but not deleted. *rm.exe* deceives you

Comment: thank you so much for such detailed investigation and for helping me to understand the problem brefly :)

Comment: and one more question please, which tools did you use to understand internal working so well?

Comment: @Jakomo - on the same volume - open `\$Recycle.Bin\<user-SID>\` (but not in explorer ! use some another file browser) and look for files ".cyg***" (however "cyg" used strange encoding and displayed as unreadable characters - https://prnt.sc/hkab5a). tools - debugger

Comment: only debugger? May I ask which debugger did you use?

Comment: @Jakomo yes, only debugger. for this task this is enough. debugger my own(private)

Comment: I see. I guess I don't have any chance to get my hands on it :D

Comment: MSYS `unlink` is similar (based on the same code, I think) but uses the prefix ".smym", which appears to be encoded bytes smuggled in surrogate codes (0x73 stored as U+DC73, which Windows allows, though it's not valid UTF-16). Note that if the drive doesn't support security (e.g. FAT32), files are moved to the root of the recycle bin, not in a subdirectory named as the user's SID. It doesn't create valid recycle bin entry pairs (meta and data), so this trash won't show up in the Windows shell. You have to manually delete it from the recycle bin using a script.